# How can one enable Visual Leak Detector via cmake in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, memory-leaks, cmake

I am using Visual Studio 17 for my projects and would like to use the Visual Leak Detector to find memory leaks.

Further the project is set up to use cmake, and thus I included the following lines of code in in my cmakelist.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic")
message("Enabling Visual Leak Detector")
find_library(VLD vld HINTS "C:/somePath/Visual Leak Detector/lib/Win64/")
find_file(VLD_H vld.h HINTS "C:/somePath/Visual Leak Detector/include")
include_directories("${VLD_H}")
link_libraries("${VLD}")
message("${VLD_H}")
message("${VLD}")
message("Enabling Visual Leak Detector Done")
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

I have however the problem, that Visual Studio doesn't seem to find  under this configuration. 
If I use the automatically included/linked libraries/directories in a solution, VLD is found, can be included and runs, making me believe that above  cmakelist.txt has just to be tweaked a bit. 
Does someone have an idea, what I could do/try?

Error: 
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'vld.h': No such file or directory
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "vld.h" main - x64-Debug

Output:

```
1> Command line: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\something\CMakeBuilds\8ab4cf5c-e7da-fe3d-9c4a-91e8ace77e1f\install\x64-Debug"  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.15.26726/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\some\Advpt\Ex1"
1> Working directory: C:\something\CMakeBuilds\8ab4cf5c-e7da-fe3d-9c4a-91e8ace77e1f\build\x64-Debug
1> Enabling Visual Leak Detector
1> C:/somePath/Visual Leak Detector/include/vld.h
1> C:/somePath/Visual Leak Detector/lib/Win64/vld.lib
1> Enabling Visual Leak Detector Done
1> -- Configuring done
1> -- Generating done
1> -- Build files have been written to: C:/something/CMakeBuilds/8ab4cf5c-e7da-fe3d-9c4a-91e8ace77e1f/build/x64-Debug
1> Starting CMake target info extraction ...
1> CMake server connection made.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted global settings.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted CTest info.
1> Collating data ...
1> Target info extraction done.
```

Comment: "that Visual Studio doesn't seem to find under this configuration." - Elaborate the problem. E.g., provide the exact error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, The error code is the following, thoughly likely not helpful.
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file "vld.h"

Comment: The error message tells that the **header file** is not found. Setting include directories ([include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/include_directories.html) command) would help in that process, but your code doesn't do that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, how do I set the include directories? Above, I added an updated version of the cmakelist.txt

Comment: You need to add include directory, which contains given header (`vld.h`). As you have corresponded `find_file` in your code, just use its results: `include_directories(${VLD_H})`. (Also it is good approach to check that given `find_file` has been succeed: `if(VLD_H)`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I updated the code, added outputs/more information and error persists, though I don't really understand why as cmake seems to find the header and library file, main still gives me the error message.

Comment: Got it. You use [find_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_file.html) which returns full **path to the file** (and your output confirms that). Instead, use [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_path.html): while its search behavior is similar, it returns **path to the directory** which contains given file. Exactly this path should be used as include directory.

Comment: I got it working now. Thank you a lot.